# Make dynamic amount of inputs individual

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to create multiple name inputs based on the selection from the drop down. Right now if I type in one input, the value of all inputs is the same. How can I make them all individual so I can dynamically post x amount of names to firebase?

```
<template>
    <div>
        <form v-on:submit.prevent="addRsvp">
            <div>
                <label>How many people are attending?</label>
                <select v-model="selected">
                    <option v-bind:value="{ number: 1 }">1</option>
                    <option v-bind:value="{ number: 2 }">2</option>
                    <option v-bind:value="{ number: 3 }">3</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label>Names:</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    v-for="n in Number(selected.number)"
                    v-bind:index="n"
                    v-model="newRsvp.name"
                    :key="n"
                />
            </div>

            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
<script>

import { db } from '../config/db';

export default {
    name: 'HomePage',
    firebase: {
        rsvp: db.ref('rsvp'),
    },
    data () {
        return {
            selected: {
                number: 2,
            },
            newRsvp: {
                name: '',
            },
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addRsvp() {
            this.$firebaseRefs.rsvp.push({
                name: this.newRsvp.name,
            })
            alert("Succeessfully added");
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: `v-model="newRsvp.name"` make it `n` dependent e.g.: `v-model="newRsvp.names[n]"`

Comment: I did this and then in my data object I set name: [] instead of name: ''